# How to pass stepper value to ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a custom cell that has 2 labels, myLabel and numLabel, and a stepper. I have my custom cell in a Swift file and XIB file. I want when I click + or - button on the stepper, my numLabel change with the value of the stepper. I don't know how to pass the stepper value to the viewController where I have my tableView. Later want to save the stepper value to CoreDate how can I do that?. I'm just a beginner. Thank you for helping.

MyCell.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "MyCell"
    
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    public func configure(with name: String, number: String) {
        myLabel.text = name
        numLabel.text = number
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var numLabel: UILabel!
        
    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

ViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.register(MyCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: MyCell.identifier)
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.configure(with: "Item 1", number: "1")
        return cell
    }


}
```

[My Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy1zx.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with a "callback" closure:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "MyCell"
    
    @IBOutlet var myStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var numLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!

    // "callback" closure - set my controller in cellForRowAt
    var callback: ((Int) -> ())?
    
    public func configure(with name: String, number: String) {
        myLabel.text = name
        numLabel.text = number
    }

    @IBAction func stepperChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        let val = Int(sender.value)
        numLabel.text = "\(val)"
        // send value back to controller via closure
        callback?(val)
    }

    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil)
    }

}
```

Then, in `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.configure(with: "Item 1", number: "1")
    
    // set the "callback' closure
    cell.callback = { (val) in
        print("Stepper in cell at \(indexPath) changed to: \(val)")
        // do what you want when the stepper value was changed
        //  such as updating your data array
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegate for a generic approach. This allows flexibility in how your cell interacts with the tableview, and enables type checking as you would expect from Swift.

Typically, for a UITableView, you would have an array of data that drives the content of the cells. In your case, let's assume that it's MyStruct (inside your view controller):

```
struct MyStruct {
    let name: String
    var value: Int
}
var myStructs: [ MyStruct ] = [
    MyStruct( name: "Name 1", value: 1 ),
    MyStruct( name: "Name 2", value: 2 ),
    MyStruct( name: "Name 3", value: 3 ) ]
```

Create `MyCellDelegate`, and place in it whatever methods that you require to communicate changes from the cell to the view controller. For example:

```
protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
    func didSet( value: Int, for myStructIndex: Int )
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate!
    var myStructIndex: Int!
    ...
}
```

For your table view, assign the delegate when dequeuing the cell, and implement the protocol.

```
class ViewController: MyCellDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath ) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        let myStruct = myStructs[indexPath.row]  // You may want to ensure that you are in bounds
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.myStructIndex = indexPath.row
        cell.configure( with: myStruct.name, number: myStruct.value )
        return cell
    }

    func didSet( value: Int, for myStructIndex: Int ) {
        //  Now MyViewController sees the change.
        myStructs[myStructIndex].value = value
    }
}
```

Lastly, in your MyCell, whenever the value changes, for example in your stepper, invoke:

```
@IBAction func stepperChanged( _ sender: UIStepper ) {
    let integerValue = Int( sender.value.round() )
    numLabel.text = "\(integerValue)"

    //  Tell the view controller about the change: what happened, and to what cell.
    self.delegate.didSet( value: integerValue, for: self.myStructIndex )
}
```